# Is it possible to have same Authority for content provider in 2 different android apps?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Can anyone explain me what will happen if I have 2 apps which individually have their own content providers, but have same authority. So if I call insert using getContentResolver(), which content provider will be called?

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain me what will happen if I have 2 apps which individually have their own content providers, but have same authority.

Whichever one you try to install second on the same device will fail to install, with a "duplicate provider authority" install error.

Comment: and what will happen if there are 2 developers who unknowingly created same authority in their onw apps. And if a user tries to install the apps developed by 2 developers, Will he not be able to install the 2nd app? Also the user being a non technical user will not unerstand the reason also right? may be a silly doubt, but better to get it solved.

Comment: Well, that's why authorities should follow app package names : prevent duplicates

Comment: @rahul: "and what will happen if there are 2 developers who unknowingly created same authority in their onw apps" -- it is very unlikely that one user will want to install both apps. If it happens, the user's attempt to install the second app will fail, with a "duplicate provider authority" error, as noted in the answer. "Will he not be able to install the 2nd app?" -- correct. "Also the user being a non technical user will not unerstand the reason also right?" -- also correct. As Guillaume suggests, have your provider authority be based off of your package name/application ID.